# Broadcast receiver not registering with onResume() while onPause() does

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm attempting to display the status of:

**battery charge (t/f)
usB charge (t/f)
battery AC charge (t/f)
battery level (in percent)**

after changing the charger connection in extended controls.

In onResume() the broadcast receiver states

> Cannot resolve method
>   'registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)

It registers in the onPause() with no issues. 
Thanks for your help, this seems like a difficult question to solve.

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    public MyReciever myReciever= new MyReciever();
    Intent intent;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                myReciever.onReceive(MainActivity.this, intent);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                intent = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
                int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;

                stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(isCharging));
                stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(usbCharge));
                stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(acCharge));
                stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(batteryPct));

                String str = stringBuilder.toString();
                TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
                display.setText(str);

            }
        };
    }
///Not Registering here
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
   protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

MyReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Intent newintent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                newintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newintent);



            }
        }
```

activity_main.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/results"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    super.onResume();
}
```

For more info please refer https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the method `registerReciever` takes 2 arguments, not 1.

These arguments are

1. The broadcast receiver to register
2. An Intent Filter

Since you are only providing the first argument, the method is not found and since there is no version of the method (overloaded method) that only takes one argument.

So in order to fix this, you would have to call the method like this:

```
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    super.onResume();
}
```

The documentation to create an IntentFilter is available here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html